# Is it possible to run a series of ruby scripts from within Intellij to run my program?

Tags: java, ruby, intellij-idea

I'm wondering if there's a way to run a series of ruby scripts that run my application. Although the application is developed in java, we use four ruby scripts to run the application. The scripts setup the environment, then start a process, and I'm wondering if I can mimic this behavior in Intellij or just run the script from Intellij. It's annoyance to have to open four command prompts every time I need to run my application.

Comment: Not to nitpick but if you need four command prompts to run four Ruby scripts, there might be some room to streamline those into a single call.

Comment: Yes perhaps, i don't mean to nitpick either, but it would be nice to just be able to launch everything from within the IDE

Comment: An IDE isn't the optimum place to try to run a process "for reals". It's fine to use for debugging and occasional utility scripts, but for real tasks I'd drop into a shell where I have full control and visibility, not what the IDE decides I should have. And, as @CharlesCaldwell suggested, having to open four shells to run four scripts seems odd. At a minimum you could write a wrapper to run each individual script serially or in parallel.